# Label size changes

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a Label, whose content is displayed by a while loop.
when i display a text in label, it displays correctly. sometime minutes, the same text displayed in the same label, and the size of the text in the control changes.

Here is the code :

```
//Form_Load :

Thread t = new Thread(displaySentences);
t.Start();


//display sentences:
void displaySentences()
{
    while(true)
    {
       if(i>=5)
          i=0;

       label4.Text = textarray[i];
       i++;

    }

}
```

the size of the text in the first iteration(i=0) is different from the size of the text in the label control in the second iteration.

Comment: What is your question? Is your label's font size changing unexpectedly?  Can you clarify what you mean by "sometime minutes, the same text displayed"?  Posting your code would be useful as well to help answer your question.

Comment: We really can't do much on this one without the relevant code sample, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you not want autosizing? Set the autosize property to false.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be looking for something elsewhere that was modifying properties on the label4 object.

Side note - should you really be spawning a thread and having that thread mess with the UI? Chris Sells wrote a series of articles in which he explained why this was a bad idea.

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code into a Windows Forms app, and my side note is coming into play:

"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

So unless you can post any additional information, or more code, or *something* that explains how you aren't getting this error, I don't know how to help you any more.